# What is total frequency count and running time (Big-O notation)?

Tags: runtime, big-o, performance

I have the following code snippet:

```
1. for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
2.    for (j = 1; j < i*i; j++) 
3.      if(j % i == 0)
4.         for(k = 0; k < j;k++)
5.            sum++;
```

What is total frequency count and running time (Big-Oh notation)?

Frequency count examine a piece code and predict the number of instructions to be executed (e.g. for each instruction predict how many times each will be encountered as the code runs.)

I try to analyse in the following way:

> Loop1 is executed n-1 times, then F.C. is 2n
>   Loop2 is executed (i*i)-1 times, then F.C. is 3(i*i)
>   total frequency count for loop1+loop2 is 2n + sum (from i=1 to n-1)3*i*i
>   I have a problem with if(j%i==0). What is loop execution here?
>   Loop4 is executed j times, then F.C. is 2j+2

Comment: It's great to have compact code, but take pity on the answerers.

Comment: Hmm... a quick look makes me think between O(n^3) and O(n^4). I'd have to get out a pencil and paper to to any better. ;)

Comment: ...also, what do you mean by "total frequency count"?

Comment: The syntax does not look right (it is chopped off at the end).

Answer (score 3):

The first 2 lines (the i and j loops) are n^3.

Line 4, the k loop is n^2. I'm tempted to mutiply them together and say n^5. But you have to consider the if on line 3.

The if statement is only true once every i itertions so you must divide by i (i.e., divide by n): (n^3)/n = n^2 giving us n^2 * n^2 = n^4.

O(n^4)

Answer (score 2):

Let's try an experimental approach, as opposed to a rigorous, mathematical one. I'm in a mood to play around. Using java:

```
    int n = 5;  long prevSum=0;
    while (n <= 320) {
         long sum = 0;
         n *= 2;

         // insert original code here   

         System.out.printf("n = %d  sum = %d", n, sum);
         if (prevSum > 0) {
             System.out.printf(" ratio %f", ((double)sum) / ((double)prevSum) ); 
         }
         System.out.println();
         prevSum = sum;
    }
```

The output is:

```
n = 10  sum = 870
n = 20  sum = 16815 ratio 19.327586
n = 40  sum = 293930 ratio 17.480226
n = 80  sum = 4909060 ratio 16.701460
n = 160  sum = 80222920 ratio 16.341809
n = 320  sum = 1297105040 ratio 16.168759
n = 640  sum = 20862446880 ratio 16.083853
```

When n is doubled sum is multiplied by about 19.3. When n is 40 sum is 293930, a ratio of 17.48 (293930 / 16815 = 17.48). As n increases the ratio approaches 16. Since 2^4 = 16 the answer is O(n^4). btw, the last line takes a long time to compute.

O(n^4)

Answer (score 1):

There's something fishy here:

```
1. for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
2.    for (j = 1; j < i*i; j++)      // <-- These two lines.
3.      if(j%i==0)                   // <-- 
4.         for(k=0; k<j;k++)
5.            sum++;
```

Since We're only executing the loop body when j is a multiple of i, why not count in i's:

```
1. for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
2.    for (j = i; j < i*i; j += i) 
3.        for(k=0; k<j;k++)
4.            sum++;
```

Which is O(n^4)

Looking at your original algorithm. The first 2 lines do O(n^3) work. Then O(n^2) of the time, (j%i == 0), we do O(n^2) more work. So The algorithm above is O(n^4).

Comment: Somehow when I hit the spacebar, it submitted my answer before I was done writing it. I probably hit tab because I wanted to indent something, and when that didn't work, hit space. Anyway, I'm done now.

Comment: I think your reasoning is wrong. If you take only the first 2 lines of the original problem statement, it's already O(n^3)... so the final answer should be higher, no?

Comment: Well, my reasoning, was for the simplified version I presented, but a simple argument would show that It's O(n^3) even without my simplification.

Comment: I think you are on to something.  redcayuga makes a pretty good point that that algorithm, as is, is O(n^4).  You've shown that it isn't *intrinsically* O(n^4) but is easily simplified to an O(n^3) algorithm.  SO...I'm upvoting both of you.

Comment: No, it's intrinsically O(n^4). Even when simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sum:

TimeComplexity =

= Sum_{i=1..n} Sum_{j=1..i^2} (1 + [j % i = 0]*Sum_{k=1..j} 1) =

= Sum_{i=1..n} Sum_{j=1..i^2} (1 + [j % i = 0]*j) =

= Sum_{i=1..n} Sum_{j=1..i^2} 1 + Sum_{i=1..n} Sum_{j=1..i^2} [j % i = 0]*j =

= Sum_{i=1..n} i^2 + Sum_{i=1..n} (i+2i+3i+...+i*i) =

= Sum_{i=1..n} i^2 + Sum_{i=1..n} i(1+2+3+...+i) =

= Sum_{i=1..n} i^2 + Sum_{i=1..n} i^2(i+1)/2 =

= Sum_{i=1..n} (i^3 + O(i^2)) =

= O(n^4).

Enjoy